# Can i create a virtualhost with vagrant and linux?

Tags: php, linux, apache

I want to create a virtualhost using vagrant, but when I create it and use the command to restart apache i get the following error:

**Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                    AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message**

Answer (score 0):

Insert `ServerName localhost` in either `httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf` in `/etc/apache2` folder and restart apache.

Comment: It is necessary that it be called **server "localhost" **? because in my Virtualhost I did it like **test.com**

Comment: Apache just isn't sure where you want serve from, so it's choosing your localhost (127.0.0.1) by default. To prevent this message from appearing, clarify that you want to serve from localhost (127.0.0.1)